# How to get the rate of a specific service - EasyPost ruby?

Tags: ruby, easypost

Trying to retrieve shipping rates for India Post but do not know how. I'm following the [Getting Started](https://www.easypost.com/getting-started/ruby.html) guide.

```
to_address = EasyPost::Address.create(
  :name => 'Dr. Steve Brule',
  :street1 => 'Ravindra Nath Tagore Marg',
  :city => 'Nagpur',
  :zip => '440001',
  :country => 'IN',
  :phone => '310-808-5243'
)
from_address = EasyPost::Address.create(
  :company => 'Bera',
  :street1 => 'Johari Bazar 14',
  :city => 'Jaipur',
  :country => 'IN',
  :zip => '302003',
  :phone => '911800112011'
)

parcel = EasyPost::Parcel.create(
  :width => 15.2,
  :length => 18,
  :height => 9.5,
  :weight => 35.1
)

shipment = EasyPost::Shipment.create(
  :to_address => to_address,
  :from_address => from_address,
  :parcel => parcel,
)

rate = shipment.lowest_rate(carriers = ['India Post'], services = ['First'])
```

Shipment do not include any rate can't figure out what is not right in this example.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you added an India Post carrier account through the EasyPost Dashboard. The Getting Started Guide does explain:

   > Note: Unless you've entered your carrier information for other carriers, you'll just receive USPS rates.
2. If you want a Shipment to only return rates for one carrier, pass that carrier account ID along with the `Shipment.create` call.

   > You can limit the CarrierAccounts to use for rating by passing the `carrier_accounts` parameter [[source]](https://www.easypost.com/docs/api/ruby.html#create-a-shipment)
3. EasyPost currently only supports Tracking for IndiaPost as you can see on [this page](https://www.easypost.com/carriers.html).

In the future, try emailing support@easypost.com for the best advice.

Comment: Unfortunately India Post is not listed among other carriers in acсount and i can't add it (https://www.easypost.com/account/carriers).

Comment: As I said, EasyPost only supports Tracking for IndiaPost. The carrier accounts are there (in almost every circumstance) so that you can purchase labels with that carrier, IF EasyPost supports purchasing labels for that carrier.